# Adding random error to a discrete variable in R

Tags: r, variables

I need to apply some econometric methodology, and I have to consider a continuous variable among my regressors. The problem is that I just have discrete variables.

Could someone tell me how I can add small random error (residual) with mean 0 to a discrete variable (one column in my data base), and save it in my data base? I'm still a R beginner.

Example: I have

```
mA <- data.frame(Asexo=c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0))
```

and I want to add a small error to `mA$Asexo` so that it became a continuous variable:

```
mA <- data.frame(Asexocontiuous=c(1.03, 0.34, 0.18, 0, 1.5))
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What form are your discrete data in -- are they integers or categorical (`factor`s in R)? Why do you "have to use a continuous variable"? Are you using a methodology that doesn't allow repeated points? I think `?jitter` and `?rnorm` (and the `Introduction to R`) would be good starting points.

Comment: Dear ben,I have just dummy variables because im workinh with microdata from studente

Comment: This still doesn't explain what you want to do.  What is the problem you are trying to solve? Can you give a simplified example of what an acceptable solution to your problem would look like?

Comment: sorry...the text was cuted...the right one...

Comment: The metodology(linked with quantilic regression) asks for at least 1 continuous variable to have a unique and well defined solution .I meant to use a aleatory error so i can make a continuons variable....do you have any idea how to do it?thanks !!

Comment: i use one of my dummy variable(say....mA$Asexo)....add a aleatory error with mean 0(can be with a normal distribution) and then it becames a continuos variable(ma$Asexocontiuous)...do you know how to do it...thanks Ben..

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the dummy variable is?  Is it a binary categorical variable?  If it's categorical with more than two possible levels then "jittering" or adding noise and treating it as continuous doesn't sound very sensible.

Comment: ex. my "data base",mA<-data.frame(Asexo=c(1,0,0,1,0)); i want to add a small aleatoy erro to mA$Asexo so that it became a continuous variable wity mean 0, then it became, for ex, mA<-data.frame(Asexocontiuous=c(1.03, 0.34,0.18,0,1.5))...

Comment: dummy variable is one that just have 1 or 0.

Comment: i dont have any other thing to use....its less worst to do it then to use a continuos variable from other data base....its a big problem in Brazil education data base....they never have the data of the students family salary or other possible continuous factors to explain the students test scores(my independent regressor).i will try to read de rnorm...thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to 'jitter' a 0/1 variable in order to make sure there are no duplicates (or to use a method that requires continuous variables), the simplest approach is

```
mydat$sexcont <- rnorm(nrow(mydat),mean=mydat$sexbinary,sd=csd)
```

where `csd` is your chosen standard deviation. A little more elegantly,

```
mydat <- transform(mydat,sexcont=rnorm(nrow(mydat),mean=sexbinary,sd=csd))
```

If `sexbinary` is a factor then use `as.numeric(sexbinary)` (or `as.numeric(sexbinary)-1` if you need it to be a 0/1 rather than a 1/2 variable)

You can also see `?jitter`, although that is more commonly used in the context of avoiding point overlaps in graphics.

Comment: if I answered your question satisfactorily, you should click to accept the answer ...

Comment: Thanks for the `jitter()` mention.